# How can I add a .Where into a .Select into an object using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a LINQ Query that I am using.  What I want to do is to order the data in `Start` and then select data for either the AndroidSpeeds or IOSSpeeds depending on if the row retrieved has IsAndroid or IsIos set to true.

Here is the query that I have so far:

```
List<LogStart> Start1 = Start
    .Where(x => x.IsPhysical == true)
    .OrderBy(g => g.DateYYMMDD)
    .Select(g => new Start2
    {
        AndroidDBSpeed = (int?)g.Where(gx => gx.IsAndroid).Select(gx => (int?)gx.DBSpeed).DefaultIfEmpty(),
        AndroidCPUSpeed = (int?)g.Where(gx => gx.IsAndroid).Select(gx => (int?)gx.CPUSpeed).DefaultIfEmpty(),
        IOSDBSpeed = (int?)g.Where(gx => gx.IsIos).Select(gx => (int?)gx.DBSpeed).DefaultIfEmpty(),
        IOSCPUSpeed = (int?)g.Where(gx => gx.IsIos).Select(gx => (int?)gx.CPUSpeed).DefaultIfEmpty(),
    })
    .ToList();
```

However, there is a problem. It's pointing to. Where and saying that

> Program.cs(46,46): Error CS1061: 'LogStart' does not contain a
>   definition for 'Where' and no accessible extension method 'Where'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'LogStart' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS1061) (Cosmos)

Does anyone have any ideas what might be wrong and how it could be fixed?

**For reference**, the following statement in the same file works okay:

```
   List<LogStart> Start2 = Start
        .Where(x => x.IsPhysical == true)
        .GroupBy(x => x.DateYYMMDD)
        .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
        .Select(g => new Start2
        {
            DateYYMMDD = g.Key,
            Devices = g.Count(),
            AndroidDBSpeed = (int?) g.Where(gx => gx.IsAndroid).Select(gx => (int?) gx.DBSpeed).DefaultIfEmpty().Average(),
            AndroidCPUSpeed = (int?)g.Where(gx => gx.IsAndroid).Select(gx => (int?)gx.CPUSpeed).DefaultIfEmpty().Average(),
            IOSDBSpeed = (int?)g.Where(gx => gx.IsIos).Select(gx => (int?)gx.DBSpeed).DefaultIfEmpty().Average(),
            IOSCPUSpeed = (int?)g.Where(gx => gx.IsIos).Select(gx => (int?)gx.CPUSpeed).DefaultIfEmpty().Average(),
        })
        .ToList();
```

Comment: Hang on a sec what is `LogStart`, is that 'Start' ? what is its definition? you say its pointing to `Where`, which `Where`? This question is lacking fundamental information

Comment: There are 5 `Where()` calls in that, we have no idea which one is on line# 46 according to the error message. We also don't know what type `Start` is. We have no idea what your `LogStart` definition looks like. I can guess `Start` is an enumerable of `LogStart`s somehow, but that's the end of deduction for me. You should clarify all these for getting a better answer. Otherwise, see if you are missing a `using System.Linq;`.

Comment: I would have liked to point to which Where but last time I included an image you said "Don't post images".  The Where that it gives a message for are the four where's at the bottom for the Speed setting.

Comment: I think that property `g.DateYYMMDD` is not `IEnumerable<T>`, therefore compiler complains to this `AndroidDBSpeed = (int?)g.Where(gx => gx.IsAndroid)`. I think you should write this `AndroidDBSpeed = g.IsAndroid ? gx.DBSpeed : (int?) null`,

Comment: @TanveerBadar - Sorry but I would have posted an image however with a previous question Michael advised me "don't include images".

Comment: If they add to the question they are fine, but if they are a replacement for text, they are not

Comment: @Alan2 No need to apologize. You can put in a comment saying which one is line 46.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The grouping is what makes the second work.

If you don't want grouping then I suspect you are looking for something like

```
var Start1 = Start
.Where(x => x.IsPhysical == true)
.OrderBy(g => g.DateYYMMDD)
.Select(g => new Start2
{
    AndroidDBSpeed  = g.IsAndroid ? (int?) g.DBSpeed :  (int?) null,
    AndroidCPUSpeed = g.IsAndroid ? (int?) g.CPUSpeed : (int?) null,
    IOSDBSpeed      = gx.IsIos    ? (int?) g.DBSpeed  : (int?) null,
    IOSCPUSpeed     = gx.IsIos    ? (int?) g.CPUSpeed : (int?) null,
})
.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is as simple as it gets. .Where is an extension method. Check your using statements - unless you are using the proper namespace (iirc System.Linq) you will not be able to get that method.

And obviously Start must be of a type supported by LINQ.

Comment: I already have: using System.Linq;  I added another LINQ statement to the question.  This one that follows the first is okay.

Comment: I'd say it is far from simple to the untrained eye TomTom. The misleading aspect of the Linq syntax is that you have to repetitively name the range variable. It had been named 'g' in the latter part of the query to reflect the change in type to a grouping caused by the GroupBy operation, but when the GroupBy operation was removed, 'g' was not renamed back to 'x' to correspond. I would say the syntax is defective in this respect. Also, over time I've found that the only tenable approach with set-based/array operations, is to assign every intermediate result to a variable, and don't chain.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Linq //Add this to the namespace, if you have not added
```

<sub>In C# LINQ provides the ability to filter the data using `Where`, `Select`, `GroupBy` etc and these are called Extension methods.
In order to use these extension methods you need to add `System.Linq` namespace which is part of `System.Core` assembly that provides access to classes that support queries that use Language-Integrated Query</sub>

> Program.cs(46,46): Error CS1061: 'LogStart' does not contain a
> definition for 'Where' and no accessible extension method 'Where'
> accepting a first argument of type 'LogStart' could be found (are you
> missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS1061) (Cosmos)

**EDIT**: *From the subsequent updates*

To use the *Where* clause you need to ensure that the type implements `IEnumerable` and at this line `g.Where(gx => gx.IsAndroid).` `g` is of type `LogStart` and does not implement `IEnumerable` therefore you cannot use `Where` extension on it

> Please note my comments that the very next c# statement in the same
> file works just fine.

That works because your are doing a `GroupBy` on the *Collection* which means that `(int?) g.Where(gx => gx.IsAndroid)` g is of type
[IGrouping<TKey,TElement>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.igrouping-2?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) which is an IEnumerable that additionally has a key

To solve, with your original code you can try to `Cast<IEnumerable>` then use `.Where` like below

```
List<LogStart> Start1 = Start
    .Where(x => x.IsPhysical == true)
    .OrderBy(g => g.DateYYMMDD).Cast<IEnumerable<LogStart>>()
    List<LogStart> Start1 = Start
    .Where(x => x.IsPhysical == true)
    .OrderBy(g => g.DateYYMMDD).Cast<IEnumerable<LogStart>>()
   .Select(g => new Start2
    {
        AndroidDBSpeed = (int?)g.Where(gx => gx.IsAndroid).Select(gx => (int?)gx.DBSpeed).DefaultIfEmpty(),
        AndroidCPUSpeed = (int?)g.Where(gx => gx.IsAndroid).Select(gx => (int?)gx.CPUSpeed).DefaultIfEmpty(),
        IOSDBSpeed = (int?)g.Where(gx => gx.IsIos).Select(gx => (int?)gx.DBSpeed).DefaultIfEmpty(),
        IOSCPUSpeed = (int?)g.Where(gx => gx.IsIos).Select(gx => (int?)gx.CPUSpeed).DefaultIfEmpty(),
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I already have: using System.Linq;  I added another LINQ statement to the question.  This one that follows the first is okay.

Comment: using System.Linq << This has been part of the namespace for the last 24 hours. Please note my comments that the very next c# statement in the same file works just fine.  Thanks